# What was clothes swapping supposed to mean for the two lead characters in Girl Asleep

Tags: plot-explanation, girl-asleep

In [Girl Asleep](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3955894/) (2015) for no apparent reason, the two leads in the movie swap clothes and go back to the party.

**What was that supposed to mean for each character?**